# Export SharePoint Site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, export

I am trying to export a site in SP 2010 with export site functionality in Central Administration but it fails. The error message in log is

```
Progress: Exporting List ConvertWordToPDF - ListInstance1.
Error: Feature '107aff13-3473-4bd7-80e9-4ec4edf1926c' for list template '10000' is not installed in this farm.
```

Seems like there is a reference to a list in the database that does not exist any more.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the list before exporting the site.

If you can't see the list under ***View All Site Content*** you could just use PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysharepoint
$web.Lists["ConvertWordToPDF - ListInstance1"].Delete()
$web.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool it will save you hours of trouble

[Content Deployment Tool](http://ittechnotebook.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-move-sharepoint-2010-site.html)

Comment: This site is not for promoting your own blog posts. Please add more details to your answers now and in the future!